# Android- Download File from link error

Tags: android, download, hyperlink

I am trying to download an epub file from a link, but after I download the file is corrupted, how I can fix this? I think the problem is that my link is:

http://st10.file.karelia.ru/25nv8s/9789d242bd127ce31991dd68fa434caa/7958c0b30a9fa22938770ac65e9f2544/principito.epub

I think it is because I am downloading from a direct link. this is the folder with original link:

http://file.karelia.ru/25nv8s/

Im just copying the link address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My be the direct link is generated dynamically every time your access it. So you cannot just simply copy the link.

Comment: I'm testing with a file from dropbox, and I just realized that is https://, and the http:// kaeira is, can this problem me?

Comment: Try open the downloaded stuff as a text file to see if it is a redirection html page.

Comment: exactly is a redirect page html, what I can do? thanks

Comment: I am not an expert on this and I do think there are many solutions on google.Can you try something like this:
URL url = new URL(url); 
HttpURLConnection ucon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
ucon.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
URL secondURL = new URL(ucon.getHeaderField("Location")); 
URLConnection conn = secondURL.openConnection();